# Oracle 11 Primary Key Generation

Tags: oracle

We have a DB table foo,

```
ID  NUMBER(10,0)    No      1
```

where the ID is the primary key.

Someone wrote an insert statement

```
INSERT INTO foo (ID, ...) VALUES (foo_squ.NEXTVAL, ...)
```

where foo_squ is a squense. And it is defined as the following:

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE  "FOO_SQU"  MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 9999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 3331 NOCACHE  NOORDER  CYCLE ;
```

The insert statement cause a duplicated primary key error.

To find out the problem, I run

```
select foo_squ.nextval from dual;
```

and I get 339. And I run

```
select id from foo where id >= 338;
```

and I get 338.

I created a trigger to solve the problem.

```
create or replace TRIGGER FOO_TRIGGER 
BEFORE INSERT ON foo FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT FOO_SQU.NEXTVAL
  INTO :NEW.ID
  FROM DUAL;
END;
```

With the trigger, the ID field needs not to be in the insert statement. That shall solve the problem. Someone, however, says that a trigger would cause a performance problem.

What would be an alternative solution?

Update:

There is a timestamp in the table. We decide to have a compound key of the ID and the timestamp to solve the problem. It is strange to me to deal with this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure how Trigger  is a solution to your problem. The sequence must have reset and the window of values for your key must have exceeded. So, the solution is to fix the Sequence range to make it sufficiently large so that there are no duplicates.

Comment: Oracle is highly optimised when it comes to getting sequences from dual. The trigger won't be a noticeable performance issue. And even so, it's still better than the problems caused by some nimrod writing an insert statement using the wrong sequence.

Comment: @KaushikNayak - the problem isn't the sequence, the problem is somebody using **the wrong sequence**. The trigger addresses the problem by enforcing the right sequence.

Comment: @KaushikNayak - Oh, the OP has edited their question to change the sequence name and made a nonsense of that response. And of course the question no longer makes sense.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I just add the squence definition. Based on the definition, I don't think its range causes the problem.

Comment: @APC : True, but OP did not tell us they used a different sequence, nor do they seem to have a rule in place to prevent users from using the wrong sequence.

Comment: vw_tsc : Are you sure the value in the table has not yet seen or populated with the numbers > `currval` of the sequence? Can you check  `select id from foo where  id >= :seq`  where `:seq` is  the result of  `select foo_squ.currval from dual`

Comment: @KaushikNayak I can't run the select statement for currval due to a complaint about undefined currval. I add the query statements based on your suggestion in my question.

Comment: It's  not possible  that `currval` gives you 339. Your sequence starts from `3331`. So, even the first time you run `nextval`, it should give you 3331.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should check if the value is no longer being passed, since as you mentioned the application execute the command FOO_SQU.NEXTVAL and not to increase its sequence twice you can add an if.

```
create or replace TRIGGER FOO_TRIGGER 
BEFORE INSERT ON foo FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  IF :NEW.ID is NULL THEN
     SELECT FOO_SQU.NEXTVAL
     INTO :NEW.ID
     FROM DUAL;
  END IF;

END;
```

As mentioned in the comments, in Oracle you will hardly have problem getting lost in the sequence, probably the wrong code was used by the application.

You use the sequence as a parameter in insert or use trigger, I believe you will not see any practical difference.